# Add java script multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have developed a widget called a list.It is simply an enhancement of html table. I have added js file for that table during enhancement. When I add multiple tables to same page, same js file is also included several times to that page. Problem is only first list's js is working but others are not. Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: can you add your code please

Comment: i think you are using same id for those multiple tables... better you could write your javascript depends to class or try to work it with dynamically... first show your html markup and js code. by this we can help you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**important**: adding several scripts in a page reduces the speed at which the page loads..try to make it all in one

and in your case you just needs one script